# How to exit the Activity UI without calling finish()

Tags: android-intent, android-activity, activity-finish

I load the Activity UI from the external library onto the screen.

Sample

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    Intent myActivity= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), myActivity.class);
    myActivityOption option = new myActivityOption();

    option.setType(2);
    myActivity.putExtra("myActivityOption", option);

    startActivityForResult(myActivity, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

This library will terminate itself with the finish() function when the Cancel button of the UI is clicked.

However, I hope that the members of the Activity class are still valid.

This is because the initialization process takes a long time.

```
private void Cancel(ImageView img){

    img.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            //MainActivity.finish();
           MainActivity.setVisible(false);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

So I tried the setVisible function, but the entire screen was blackened and the previous UI did not appear.

How do I get back to the previous screen without using the finish() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
use setFlag() method.

//like this

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)
```